# Popup Form in Website VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, forms, drop-down-menu, popup

I am in the process of building a website in Visual Studio 2010 using Visual Basic and I am trying to have an item in a `Drop Down List` when clicked, it will open a dialog box that will prompt the user to enter in some information. I have tried searching i haven't found any code that works. Here is the code I have so far;

```
Protected Sub MonthDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MonthDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged
    If MonthDropDownList.SelectedValue = "Add Month" Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at the jQueryUI dialog? http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ Of course this would require you to open the dialog with client side javascript code rather than responding the event server-side, but this is probably the best way of doing it anyway

Comment: @James S That looks really cool but I want to stick with Visual Basic if I can.

Comment: However you do it, opening a popup window on the client is something that has to be done with client side script. If you definitely want to keep that round trip to the server when the selected index is changed then you could go along the lines of adding a panel to the page (which the server side script sets to visible). The panel would include the popup form and a little bit of javascript to make it appear as a popup dialog rather than inline. the jQuery dialog is just one way of doing this bit